# Как изменить прозрачность стрелки в slick-slider, при помощи чистого JS ,когда достигается последний слайд?

Tags: javascript

```
         <div class="carousel">
                    <div><img src="img/slide.png" alt="slider_1"></div>
                    <div><img src="img/slide.png" alt="slider_2"></div>
                    <div><img src="img/slide.png" alt="slider_3"></div>
                </div>
        <script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.0.min.js"></script>
    <script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-migrate-1.2.1.min.js"></script>
    <!-- <script src="js/slick.min.js"></script>     -->
    <script type="text/javascript" src="//cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/slick-carousel@1.8.1/slick/slick.min.js"></script>
    <script src="js/wow.min.js"></script>
    <script src="js/index.js"></script>


SCSS:
    .carousel{
    position: relative;
    margin: 0 auto;
    width: 1240px;
    height: 625px;
    border-radius: 45px;
    background-color: #191A23;
    img{
        width: 100%;
    }
    .slick-slide{
        padding: 84px 0 64px 0;
        margin-left: 50px;
    }
    .slick-slide{
        width: 500px;
    }
    .slick-prev, .slick-next{
        position: absolute;
        top: 435px;
        right: 396px;
        border: none;
        background-color:#191A23;
        img{
            width: 20px;
        }

    }
    .slick-prev{
        left: 396px;
        right: auto;
    }
    .slick-dots{
        display: flex;
        justify-content: center;
        text-align: center;
        list-style: none;
        margin: 0;
        padding: 0;
        padding: 124px 0 64px 0;
    }
    .slick-dots li button {
        content: url('../../icons/Vector.svg');
        font-size: 0;
        height: 14px;
        width: 14px;
        border: none;
        margin: 0 19px 0 19px;
    }
}
```

inex.js:

```
        const carousel = document.querySelector(".carousel");
        const slides = document.querySelectorAll('.slick-slide');
        const settings = {
            speed: 1000,
            // adaptiveHeight: true,
            infinite: false,
            dots: true,
            slidesToShow: 2.99,
            slidesToScroll: 1,
            centerMode: true,
            variableWidth: true,
            prevArrow: '<button type="button" class="slick-prev" style="opacity: {{prevArrowOpacity}}><svg width="24" height="24" viewBox="0 0 24 24" fill="none" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"><path d="M22 13.5C22.8284 13.5 23.5 12.8284 23.5 12C23.5 11.1716 22.8284 10.5 22 10.5L22 13.5ZM0.939341 10.9393C0.353554 11.5251 0.353554 12.4749 0.93934 13.0607L10.4853 22.6066C11.0711 23.1924 12.0208 23.1924 12.6066 22.6066C13.1924 22.0208 13.1924 21.0711 12.6066 20.4853L4.12132 12L12.6066 3.51472C13.1924 2.92893 13.1924 1.97918 12.6066 1.3934C12.0208 0.807611 11.0711 0.807611 10.4853 1.3934L0.939341 10.9393ZM22 10.5L2 10.5L2 13.5L22 13.5L22 10.5Z" fill="white"/></svg></button>',
            nextArrow: '<button type="button" class="slick-next" style="opacity: {{nextArrowOpacity}}><svg width="24" height="24" viewBox="0 0 24 24" fill="none" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"><path d="M2 10.5C1.17157 10.5 0.5 11.1716 0.5 12C0.5 12.8284 1.17157 13.5 2 13.5L2 10.5ZM23.0607 13.0607C23.6464 12.4749 23.6464 11.5251 23.0607 10.9393L13.5147 1.3934C12.9289 0.807613 11.9792 0.807613 11.3934 1.3934C10.8076 1.97919 10.8076 2.92893 11.3934 3.51472L19.8787 12L11.3934 20.4853C10.8076 21.0711 10.8076 22.0208 11.3934 22.6066C11.9792 23.1924 12.9289 23.1924 13.5147 22.6066L23.0607 13.0607ZM2 13.5L22 13.5L22 10.5L2 10.5L2 13.5Z" fill="white"/></svg></button>',
            responsive: [
                {
                    breakpoint: 767,
                    settings: {
                        slidesToShow: 1.99,
                        dots: false
                    }
                },
                {
                    breakpoint: 575,
                    settings: {
                        slidesToShow: 1,
                        dots: false
                    }
                }
            ]
        };
    
        
        if (carousel) {
            $('.carousel').slick(settings)
            $('.carousel').on('afterChange', function(event, slick, currentIndex){
                changeArrows(prevArrow, nextArrow);
            })
        }
        
        function changeArrows(prevArrow, nextArrow) {
            const currentIndex = Array.from(slides).findIndex(slide => slide.classList.contains("slick-current"));
            
            const prevArrowOpacity = currentIndex === 0 ? '0.3' : '1' ;
            const nextArrowOpacity = currentIndex === 2 ? '0.3' : '1' ;
           
            // Обновляем настройки с новыми значениями opacity
            const updatedSettings = {
                ...settings,
                prevArrow: settings.prevArrow.replace('{{prevArrowOpacity}}', prevArrowOpacity),
                nextArrow: settings.nextArrow.replace('{{nextArrowOpacity}}', nextArrowOpacity),
            };
    
            // Переинициализация слайдера с новыми настройками
            $('.carousel').slick('unslick');
            $('.carousel').slick(updatedSettings);
        }




    /*! WOW wow.js - v1.3.0 - 2016-10-04
* https://wowjs.uk
* Copyright (c) 2016 Thomas Grainger; Licensed MIT */!function(a,b){if("function"==typeof define&&define.amd)define(["module","exports"],b);else if("undefined"!=typeof exports)b(module,exports);else{var c={exports:{}};b(c,c.exports),a.WOW=c.exports}}(this,function(a,b){"use strict";function c(a,b){if(!(a instanceof b))throw new TypeError("Cannot call a class as a function")}function d(a,b){return b.indexOf(a)>=0}function e(a,b){for(var c in b)if(null==a[c]){var d=b[c];a[c]=d}return a}function f(a){return/Android|webOS|iPhone|iPad|iPod|BlackBerry|IEMobile|Opera Mini/i.test(a)}function g(a){var b=arguments.length<=1||void 0===arguments[1]?!1:arguments[1],c=arguments.length<=2||void 0===arguments[2]?!1:arguments[2],d=arguments.length<=3||void 0===arguments[3]?null:arguments[3],e=void 0;return null!=document.createEvent?(e=document.createEvent("CustomEvent"),e.initCustomEvent(a,b,c,d)):null!=document.createEventObject?(e=document.createEventObject(),e.eventType=a):e.eventName=a,e}function h(a,b){null!=a.dispatchEvent?a.dispatchEvent(b):b in(null!=a)?a[b]():"on"+b in(null!=a)&&a["on"+b]()}function i(a,b,c){null!=a.addEventListener?a.addEventListener(b,c,!1):null!=a.attachEvent?a.attachEvent("on"+b,c):a[b]=c}function j(a,b,c){null!=a.removeEventListener?a.removeEventListener(b,c,!1):null!=a.detachEvent?a.detachEvent("on"+b,c):delete a[b]}function k(){return"innerHeight"in window?window.innerHeight:document.documentElement.clientHeight}Object.defineProperty(b,"__esModule",{value:!0});var l,m,n=function(){function a(a,b){for(var c=0;c<b.length;c++){var d=b[c];d.enumerable=d.enumerable||!1,d.configurable=!0,"value"in d&&(d.writable=!0),Object.defineProperty(a,d.key,d)}}return function(b,c,d){return c&&a(b.prototype,c),d&&a(b,d),b}}(),o=window.WeakMap||window.MozWeakMap||function(){function a(){c(this,a),this.keys=[],this.values=[]}return n(a,[{key:"get",value:function(a){for(var b=0;b<this.keys.length;b++){var c=this.keys[b];if(c===a)return this.values[b]}}},{key:"set",value:function(a,b){for(var c=0;c<this.keys.length;c++){var d=this.keys[c];if(d===a)return this.values[c]=b,this}return this.keys.push(a),this.values.push(b),this}}]),a}(),p=window.MutationObserver||window.WebkitMutationObserver||window.MozMutationObserver||(m=l=function(){function a(){c(this,a),"undefined"!=typeof console&&null!==console&&(console.warn("MutationObserver is not supported by your browser."),console.warn("WOW.js cannot detect dom mutations, please call .sync() after loading new content."))}return n(a,[{key:"observe",value:function(){}}]),a}(),l.notSupported=!0,m),q=window.getComputedStyle||function(a){var b=/(\-([a-z]){1})/g;return{getPropertyValue:function(c){"float"===c&&(c="styleFloat"),b.test(c)&&c.replace(b,function(a,b){return b.toUpperCase()});var d=a.currentStyle;return(null!=d?d[c]:void 0)||null}}},r=function(){function a(){var b=arguments.length<=0||void 0===arguments[0]?{}:arguments[0];c(this,a),this.defaults={boxClass:"wow",animateClass:"animated",offset:0,mobile:!0,live:!0,callback:null,scrollContainer:null,resetAnimation:!0},this.animate=function(){return"requestAnimationFrame"in window?function(a){return window.requestAnimationFrame(a)}:function(a){return a()}}(),this.vendors=["moz","webkit"],this.start=this.start.bind(this),this.resetAnimation=this.resetAnimation.bind(this),this.scrollHandler=this.scrollHandler.bind(this),this.scrollCallback=this.scrollCallback.bind(this),this.scrolled=!0,this.config=e(b,this.defaults),null!=b.scrollContainer&&(this.config.scrollContainer=document.querySelector(b.scrollContainer)),this.animationNameCache=new o,this.wowEvent=g(this.config.boxClass)}return n(a,[{key:"init",value:function(){this.element=window.document.documentElement,d(document.readyState,["interactive","complete"])?this.start():i(document,"DOMContentLoaded",this.start),this.finished=[]}},{key:"start",value:function(){var a=this;if(this.stopped=!1,this.boxes=[].slice.call(this.element.querySelectorAll("."+this.config.boxClass)),this.all=this.boxes.slice(0),this.boxes.length)if(this.disabled())this.resetStyle();else for(var b=0;b<this.boxes.length;b++){var c=this.boxes[b];this.applyStyle(c,!0)}if(this.disabled()||(i(this.config.scrollContainer||window,"scroll",this.scrollHandler),i(window,"resize",this.scrollHandler),this.interval=setInterval(this.scrollCallback,50)),this.config.live){var d=new p(function(b){for(var c=0;c<b.length;c++)for(var d=b[c],e=0;e<d.addedNodes.length;e++){var f=d.addedNodes[e];a.doSync(f)}});d.observe(document.body,{childList:!0,subtree:!0})}}},{key:"stop",value:function(){this.stopped=!0,j(this.config.scrollContainer||window,"scroll",this.scrollHandler),j(window,"resize",this.scrollHandler),null!=this.interval&&clearInterval(this.interval)}},{key:"sync",value:function(){p.notSupported&&this.doSync(this.element)}},{key:"doSync",value:function(a){if("undefined"!=typeof a&&null!==a||(a=this.element),1===a.nodeType){a=a.parentNode||a;for(var b=a.querySelectorAll("."+this.config.boxClass),c=0;c<b.length;c++){var e=b[c];d(e,this.all)||(this.boxes.push(e),this.all.push(e),this.stopped||this.disabled()?this.resetStyle():this.applyStyle(e,!0),this.scrolled=!0)}}}},{key:"show",value:function(a){return this.applyStyle(a),a.className=a.className+" "+this.config.animateClass,null!=this.config.callback&&this.config.callback(a),h(a,this.wowEvent),this.config.resetAnimation&&(i(a,"animationend",this.resetAnimation),i(a,"oanimationend",this.resetAnimation),i(a,"webkitAnimationEnd",this.resetAnimation),i(a,"MSAnimationEnd",this.resetAnimation)),a}},{key:"applyStyle",value:function(a,b){var c=this,d=a.getAttribute("data-wow-duration"),e=a.getAttribute("data-wow-delay"),f=a.getAttribute("data-wow-iteration");return this.animate(function(){return c.customStyle(a,b,d,e,f)})}},{key:"resetStyle",value:function(){for(var a=0;a<this.boxes.length;a++){var b=this.boxes[a];b.style.visibility="visible"}}},{key:"resetAnimation",value:function(a){if(a.type.toLowerCase().indexOf("animationend")>=0){var b=a.target||a.srcElement;b.className=b.className.replace(this.config.animateClass,"").trim()}}},{key:"customStyle",value:function(a,b,c,d,e){return b&&this.cacheAnimationName(a),a.style.visibility=b?"hidden":"visible",c&&this.vendorSet(a.style,{animationDuration:c}),d&&this.vendorSet(a.style,{animationDelay:d}),e&&this.vendorSet(a.style,{animationIterationCount:e}),this.vendorSet(a.style,{animationName:b?"none":this.cachedAnimationName(a)}),a}},{key:"vendorSet",value:function(a,b){for(var c in b)if(b.hasOwnProperty(c)){var d=b[c];a[""+c]=d;for(var e=0;e<this.vendors.length;e++){var f=this.vendors[e];a[""+f+c.charAt(0).toUpperCase()+c.substr(1)]=d}}}},{key:"vendorCSS",value:function(a,b){for(var c=q(a),d=c.getPropertyCSSValue(b),e=0;e<this.vendors.length;e++){var f=this.vendors[e];d=d||c.getPropertyCSSValue("-"+f+"-"+b)}return d}},{key:"animationName",value:function(a){var b=void 0;try{b=this.vendorCSS(a,"animation-name").cssText}catch(c){b=q(a).getPropertyValue("animation-name")}return"none"===b?"":b}},{key:"cacheAnimationName",value:function(a){return this.animationNameCache.set(a,this.animationName(a))}},{key:"cachedAnimationName",value:function(a){return this.animationNameCache.get(a)}},{key:"scrollHandler",value:function(){this.scrolled=!0}},{key:"scrollCallback",value:function(){if(this.scrolled){this.scrolled=!1;for(var a=[],b=0;b<this.boxes.length;b++){var c=this.boxes[b];if(c){if(this.isVisible(c)){this.show(c);continue}a.push(c)}}this.boxes=a,this.boxes.length||this.config.live||this.stop()}}},{key:"offsetTop",value:function(a){for(;void 0===a.offsetTop;)a=a.parentNode;for(var b=a.offsetTop;a.offsetParent;)a=a.offsetParent,b+=a.offsetTop;return b}},{key:"isVisible",value:function(a){var b=a.getAttribute("data-wow-offset")||this.config.offset,c=this.config.scrollContainer&&this.config.scrollContainer.scrollTop||window.pageYOffset,d=c+Math.min(this.element.clientHeight,k())-b,e=this.offsetTop(a),f=e+a.clientHeight;return d>=e&&f>=c}},{key:"disabled",value:function(){return!this.config.mobile&&f(navigator.userAgent)}}]),a}();b["default"]=r,a.exports=b["default"]});

> Должно выглядеть как на картинке.
> Какие правки нужно внести в код , чтобы все заработало
> У меня по какой-то причине переменные nextArrow
и prevArrow имеют значение null, хотя в консоли в браузере они у меня имели значение элемента кнопки , но vscode значение у них null, по этой причине я не могу им присвоить стили opacity через nextArrows.style.opacity = '0.3' и так далее. Уже стал пробовать их находить через объект settings в котором они находятся , но это тоже не работает.


[![введите сюда описание изображения][1]][1]
        


  [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/lyBX1.png
```

Comment: Не понятно, что находится в этих библиотеках <script src="js/wow.min.js"></script>
<script src="js/index.js"></script> и где .css-файл.

Comment: @Kosmos дополнил . если это поможет Вам разобраться в чем дело , буду благодарен

Answer (score 1):

В данном плагине это уже реализовано

Для этого используется `.class` - `.slick-disabled`

Пример

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('.your-class').slick({
    infinite: false,
    prevArrow: '<button type="button" class="slick-prev"><svg width="24" height="24" viewBox="0 0 24 24" fill="none" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"><path d="M22 13.5C22.8284 13.5 23.5 12.8284 23.5 12C23.5 11.1716 22.8284 10.5 22 10.5L22 13.5ZM0.939341 10.9393C0.353554 11.5251 0.353554 12.4749 0.93934 13.0607L10.4853 22.6066C11.0711 23.1924 12.0208 23.1924 12.6066 22.6066C13.1924 22.0208 13.1924 21.0711 12.6066 20.4853L4.12132 12L12.6066 3.51472C13.1924 2.92893 13.1924 1.97918 12.6066 1.3934C12.0208 0.807611 11.0711 0.807611 10.4853 1.3934L0.939341 10.9393ZM22 10.5L2 10.5L2 13.5L22 13.5L22 10.5Z" fill="white"/></svg></button>',
    nextArrow: '<button type="button" class="slick-next"><svg width="24" height="24" viewBox="0 0 24 24" fill="none" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"><path d="M2 10.5C1.17157 10.5 0.5 11.1716 0.5 12C0.5 12.8284 1.17157 13.5 2 13.5L2 10.5ZM23.0607 13.0607C23.6464 12.4749 23.6464 11.5251 23.0607 10.9393L13.5147 1.3934C12.9289 0.807613 11.9792 0.807613 11.3934 1.3934C10.8076 1.97919 10.8076 2.92893 11.3934 3.51472L19.8787 12L11.3934 20.4853C10.8076 21.0711 10.8076 22.0208 11.3934 22.6066C11.9792 23.1924 12.9289 23.1924 13.5147 22.6066L23.0607 13.0607ZM2 13.5L22 13.5L22 10.5L2 10.5L2 13.5Z" fill="white"/></svg></button>',
  });
});
```

```css
.slick-slide {
  border: 1px solid #000;
  text-align: center;
}

.slick-slider .slick-arrow {
  background-color: #000;
  width: 40px;
  height: 40px;
  z-index: 99;
}

.slick-slider .slick-arrow::before {
  display: none;
}

.slick-slider .slick-arrow.slick-disabled {
  opacity: .5;
  pointer-events: none;
}

.slick-slider .slick-arrow:hover,
.slick-slider .slick-arrow:focus,
.slick-slider .slick-arrow:active {
  background-color: #000;
}

.slick-slider .slick-prev {
  left: 0;
}

.slick-slider .slick-next {
  right: 0;
}

.your-class-2 .slick-arrow.slick-disabled {
  opacity: 0;
}
```

```html
<!-- Add the slick-theme.css if you want default styling -->
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/slick-carousel@1.8.1/slick/slick.css" />
<!-- Add the slick-theme.css if you want default styling -->
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/slick-carousel@1.8.1/slick/slick-theme.css" />

<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.0.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/slick-carousel@1.8.1/slick/slick.min.js"></script>

<h2>Вариант 1</h2>
<div class="your-class">
  <div>
    <h3>1</h3>
  </div>
  <div>
    <h3>2</h3>
  </div>
  <div>
    <h3>3</h3>
  </div>
  <div>
    <h3>4</h3>
  </div>
  <div>
    <h3>5</h3>
  </div>
  <div>
    <h3>6</h3>
  </div>
</div>


<h2>Вариант 2</h2>
<div class="your-class your-class-2">
  <div>
    <h3>1</h3>
  </div>
  <div>
    <h3>2</h3>
  </div>
  <div>
    <h3>3</h3>
  </div>
  <div>
    <h3>4</h3>
  </div>
  <div>
    <h3>5</h3>
  </div>
  <div>
    <h3>6</h3>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Спасибо , помогло)